# Systemd Environment and EnvironmentFile not working

Tags: centos7, systemd

I've built an application and a systemd unit for it. The systemd unit works fine, but as the dev and prod environments have diverged I've started moving config out to environment variables and I can't seem to get them to work in systemd.

I've tried system-wide environment variables, and they're visible to the OS, but not the program, so i started looking at building them into systemd units.

First I tried using EnvironmentFile

I created an environment file that simply had

```
LCSQLH=localhost
LCSQLU=application
```

in it as `/etc/lc.sh` and

```
[Unit]
Description=Service for this app

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/lc.sh
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python /opt/app/__init__.py
```

did a `systemctl --system daemon-reload` but no, my app errored:

`Jan 27 14:24:59 machine.host env[630]: KeyError: 'LCSQLU'`

I saw some had:

`EnvironmentFile=-/etc/lc.sh`

I tried that.... nope...

So I tried putting them in individually

```
[Service]
Environment="LCSQLH=localhost"
Environment="LCSQLU=application"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python /opt/app/__init__.py
```

Yet again, no...

So I heard about the idea of `/etc/systemd/service_name.service.d` so I put a service.conf in there with the environments in (same format as above) but no...

My application has no access to these environment variables.

If I export them (either manually in my shell or using /etc/profile.d/) and run my app directly it works, so it is that these aren't being set rather than an app issue.

This is Centos 7.3 and I've chosen environment variables rather than a hardcoded config because it may run on either linux or windows, so don't want to bury a config file in /etc/

Comment: Seems to be working here, are you running `systemctl daemon-reload` and stop start your application each time to test your modifications?

Comment: Having the same problem on CentOS8, and this issue has (3.5 years after asking) 31k views. Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: How depressing to run into this problem again, and then find my own comment. Sorry old me, it still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into the same trouble on RHEL 7.3 and found [this](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd#EnvironmentFiles_and_support_for_.2Fetc.2Fsysconfig_files):

> You may then refer to variables set in the `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` file with `${FOOBAR}` and `$FOOBAR`, in the `ExecStart` lines (and related lines).

This makes me think that the purpose for `Environment` and `EnvironmentFile` is not at all what you and I expected (setting environment variables for the process started by the systemd unit), but only applies for the immediate expansion of the `ExecStart` line.

Perhaps I'm completely off-base and this is a bug in systemd (I hope so). But I stopped going down the path you are trying and did it another way: In my case I needed to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so I did that via creating `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/new_file.conf` and then running `ldconfig`. I also attempted to use system-wide variables in `/etc/profile.d/new_file.sh`, but apparently setting just `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was enough for this service (mariadb) and so I don't actually know if the variables I was setting in `/etc/profile.d/new_file.sh` were functioning.

Answer (score 37):

`Environment` and `EnvironmentFile` set the variables, usable by the unit, but like the `sh` command, does not export it to child processes. For that, you also need to list it in `PassEnvironment`, just as you would with the `export` shell command. See [the systemd documentation on EnvironmentFile and PassEnvironment](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=)

Also, note that the contents of an EnvironmentFile is not a shell script, but key-value pairs that look rather too much like sh, so naming it with a `.sh` extension is misleading.

Comment: Also worth noting that a careful reading of those docs also reveals why these variables seem to pass through for some configurations `"system services by default do not automatically inherit any environment variables [...] However, in case of the user service manager all environment variables are passed to the executed processes"`

Comment: I just tested this out using `ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -l -c 'env >/tmp/ingest.err'` and env. var's set using `Environment=` and `EnvironmentFile=` and `systemctl set-environment...` *do* show up in the env of the unit...even if it's a system unit.  The only explanation I can must is that `PassEnvironment` means to pass variables in the env. of the systemd process itself "through" (see comment https://superuser.com/a/728962/39364).  FWIW...