# Only certain environment variables are set in systemd

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd file starting a JupyterHub:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyterhub

[Service]
User=root
Environment="PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/spark/bin:/opt/hadoop/bin"
Environment="HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop"
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/jupyterhub -f /opt/jupyter/jupyterhub_config.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, only the `PATH` variable is set, the settings for `HADOOP_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` are ignored.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Systemd Environment and EnvironmentFile not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/828999/systemd-environment-and-environmentfile-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, it might be your use of quotes. Systemd is that rare beast that can handle multiple equal signs without getting horribly confused (in the ways you'd expect).

```
[Service]
Environment=HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

It doesn't *look* like it'll work, but I have units on my system written that way and they work.